# Running two socket applications within one program

Tags: c, sockets, ssh, distributed, libssh

I have two C/C++ socket programs, say `server` and `client`, and both communicate to each other through `read` and `write`. The entire flow works fine (i.e., communication, read, write) when I run the two programs on two separate terminals in localhost. To avoid manually starting the `client` program, I use `system(exec_cmd_to_run_client_program)` in my server program. However, doing so doesn't give me the correct result as that of two separate terminals. I do see `server` and `client` running in the job monitor, but the communication in between seems never happens. What could be the problem?

Also I tried using ssh library `libssh` in the `server` program to open a new ssh session and send execution command to run the `client` program. Again I see the same result as system call. Both programs showed up in the job monitor but communication never happens. Did I miss something?

Comment: `man system(): [...]and returns after the command has been completed.[...]`.

Comment: Run the server on one thread and the system command on a different thread.

Comment: Use `fork` and `execl` to start the client so the server can continue running.

Comment: @cup - threads are probably not a good idea if the code isn't already thread-safe. Better to use separate processes but arrange it so that the parent can run parallel with the child.

Comment: Thanks all. One thing I just tried works. I ass "&" right after the command for system call.

Comment: @Jes: Yes that's one way of doing it, although checking for the return code will not work with the `system` call anymore, and using the POSIX process API is more portable.